# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes, predict

i am trying to find a predicted Y value (output is numerical) with x inputs using strings (eg. Business type, Department and Region).  After using this :

```
print(model.predict([['Finance and Control'], ['EMEA'], ['Professional Services']]))
```

it returned this error : `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'predict'`

```
import pickle
model = pickle.load(open('model3.pkl','rb'))
print(model.predict([['Finance and Control'], ['EMEA'], ['Professional Services']]))
```

[Sample array after OHE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCDNx.jpg)

Comment: potentially useful : https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/25673/attributeerror-numpy-ndarray-object-has-no-attribute-predict

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue as this, though without additional context, I'm not sure our errors derive from the same problem. However, the resolution I arrived at may help someone in the future as they go down the SO rabbit hole.

Using **`sklearn-0.20`**,

```py
import joblib
model = joblib.load('model.pkl')
model.predict(previously_loaded_data)
```

Resulted in

```sh
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

**However, the following allowed me to load the actual model and use its predict method:**

```py
from sklearn.externals import joblib
model = joblib.load('model.pkl')
model.predict(previously_loaded_data)
```

[`sklearn.externals.joblib` is deprecated since `sklearn-0.23+`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61895560/12810054), but my use case required `sklearn-0.20`.