# ImportError: cannot import name 'joblib' from 'sklearn.externals'

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, joblib, doc2vec

I am trying to load my saved model from `s3` using `joblib`

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import json
import subprocess
import sqlalchemy
from sklearn.externals import joblib

ENV = 'dev'
model_d2v = load_d2v('model_d2v_version_002', ENV)

def load_d2v(fname, env):
    model_name = fname
    if env == 'dev':
        try: 
            model=joblib.load(model_name)
        except:
            s3_base_path='s3://sd-flikku/datalake/doc2vec_model'
            path = s3_base_path+'/'+model_name
            command = "aws s3 cp {} {}".format(path,model_name).split()
            print('loading...'+model_name)
            subprocess.call(command)
            model=joblib.load(model_name)
    else:
        s3_base_path='s3://sd-flikku/datalake/doc2vec_model'
        path = s3_base_path+'/'+model_name
        command = "aws s3 cp {} {}".format(path,model_name).split()
        print('loading...'+model_name)
        subprocess.call(command)
        model=joblib.load(model_name)
    return model
```

But I get this error:

```
    from sklearn.externals import joblib
ImportError: cannot import name 'joblib' from 'sklearn.externals' (C:\Users\prane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\__init__.py)
```

Then I tried installing `joblib` directly by doing

```
import joblib
```

but it gave me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in load_d2v_from_s3
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 585, in load
    obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 504, in _unpickle
    obj = unpickler.load()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 1088, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 1376, in load_global
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 1426, in find_class
    __import__(module, level=0)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.externals.joblib'
```

Can you tell me how to solve this?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It looks like your existing pickle save file (`model_d2v_version_002`) encodes a reference module in a non-standard location – a `joblib` that's in `sklearn.externals.joblib` rather than at top-level.

The current `scikit-learn` documentation only talks about a top-level `joblib` – eg in [3.4.1 Persistence example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html) – but I do see a [reference in someone else's old issue to a DeprecationWarning](https://github.com/EpistasisLab/tpot/issues/869) in `scikit-learn` version 0.21 about an older `scikit.external.joblib` variant going away:

> Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib_init_.py:15:
>   DeprecationWarning: sklearn.externals.joblib is deprecated in 0.21 and
>   will be removed in 0.23. Please import this functionality directly
>   from joblib, which can be installed with: pip install joblib. If this
>   warning is raised when loading pickled models, you may need to
>   re-serialize those models with scikit-learn 0.21+.

'Deprecation' means marking something as inadvisable to rely-upon, as it is likely to be discontinued in a future release (often, but not always, with a recommended newer way to do the same thing).

I suspect your `model_d2v_version_002` file was saved from an older version of `scikit-learn`, and you're now using `scikit-learn` (aka `sklearn`) version 0.23+ which has totally removed the `sklearn.external.joblib` variation. Thus your file can't be directly or easily loaded to your current environment.

But, per the `DeprecationWarning`, you can probably temporarily use an older `scikit-learn` version to load the file the old way once, then re-save it with the now-preferred way. Given the warning info, this would probably require `scikit-learn` version 0.21.x or 0.22.x, but if you know exactly which version your `model_d2v_version_002` file was saved from, I'd try to use that. The steps would roughly be:

- create a temporary working environment (or roll back your current working environment) with the older `sklearn`
- do imports something like:

```
import sklearn.external.joblib as extjoblib
import joblib
```

- `extjoblib.load()` your old file as you'd planned, but then immediately re-`joblib.dump()` the file using the top-level `joblib`. (You likely want to use a distinct name, to keep the older file around, just in case.)
- move/update to your real, modern environment, and only `import joblib` (top level) to use `joblib.load()` - no longer having any references to `sklearn.external.joblib' in either your code, or your stored pickle files.

Answer (score 247):

You should directly use

```
import joblib
```

instead of

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
```

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.externals.joblib'

Comment: To install **joblib** use **pip** command `python3 -m pip install joblib`

Answer (score 19):

You can import `joblib` directly by installing it as a dependency and using `import joblib`,

[Documentation](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: I treid installing joblib directly but it gave me

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.externals.joblib'

Comment: Did you install it with `pip` beforehand?

Comment: joblib comes as part of Anaconda, and this worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe your code is outdated. For anyone who aims to use `fetch_mldata` in digit handwritten project, you should `fetch_openml` instead. ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47324921/cant-load-mnist-original-dataset-using-sklearn/52297457))

In old version of sklearn:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original')
```

In **sklearn 0.23** (stable release):

```
import sklearn.externals
import joblib
    
dataset = datasets.fetch_openml("mnist_784")

features = np.array(dataset.data, 'int16')
labels = np.array(dataset.target, 'int')
```

For more info about deprecating `fetch_mldata` see scikit-learn [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/0.20/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.fetch_mldata.html)

Answer (score 5):

none of the answers below works for me, with a little changes this modification was ok for me

```
import sklearn.externals as extjoblib
import joblib
```

Answer (score 4):

for this error, I had to directly use the following and it worked like a charm:

```
import joblib
```

Simple

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem

What I did not realize was that joblib *was already installed!*

so what you have to do is replace

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
```

with

```
import joblib
```

and that is it

Answer (score 2):

In case the execution / call to joblib is within another .py program instead of your own (in such case even you have installed joblib, it still causes error from within the calling python programme unless you change the code, i thought would be messy), I tried to create a hardlink:

(windows version)

Python> import joblib

then inside your sklearn path  >......\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals

> mklink /J ./joblib   .....\Lib\site-packages\joblib

(you can work out the above using a ! or %, !mklink....... or %mklink...... inside your Python juptyter notebook , or use python OS command...)

This effectively create a virtual folder of joblib within the "externals" folder

Remarks:
Of course to be more version resilient, your code has to check for the version of sklearn is >= 0.23 again before hand.

This would be alternative to changing sklearn vesrion.

[image: Hardlink for a virtual folder of joblib]

Answer (score 2):

When getting error:

**from sklearn.externals import joblib** it deprecated older version.

For new version follow:

1. conda install -c anaconda scikit-learn  (install using "Anaconda Promt")
2. import joblib (Jupyter Notebook)

Answer (score -1):

After a long investigation, given my computer setup, I've found that was because an SSL certificate was required to download the dataset.