# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while loading model from s3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, joblib, doc2vec

I have recently saved a model into s3 using joblib

model_doc is the model object

```
import subprocess
import joblib

save_d2v_to_s3_current_doc2vec_model(model_doc,"doc2vec_model")

def save_d2v_to_s3_current_doc2vec_model(model,fname):
    model_name = fname
    joblib.dump(model,model_name)
    s3_base_path = 's3://sd-flikku/datalake/current_doc2vec_model'
    path = s3_base_path+'/'+model_name
    command = "aws s3 cp {} {}".format(model_name,path).split()
    print('saving...'+model_name)
    subprocess.call(command)
```

It was successful, but after that when i try to load the model back from s3 it gives me an error

```
model = load_d2v("doc2vec_model")

def load_d2v(fname):
    model_name = fname
    s3_base_path='s3://sd-flikku/datalake/current_doc2vec_model'
    path = s3_base_path+'/'+model_name  
    command = "aws s3 cp {} {}".format(path,model_name).split()
    print('loading...'+model_name)
    subprocess.call(command)
    model=joblib.load(model_name)
    return model
```

This is the error i get:

```
loading...doc2vec_model
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in load_d2v
  File "C:\Users\prane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 339, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\prane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\prane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I don't even understand why it is saying File not found, this was the path i used to save the model but now i'm unable to get the model back from s3. Please help me!!

Comment: Have you checked, is it in actuality in s3? What's the path in s3 of the file?

Comment: It's 's3://sd-flikku/datalake/current_doc2vec_model/doc2vec_model

Comment: `doc2vec_model` is a single file, not a folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that rather than your generic `print()` lines, showing your intent, you should print the *actual `command` you've composed*, to verify that it makes sense upon observation.

If it does, then also try that *exact same `aws ...` command* directly, at the command prompt where you had been launching your `python` code, to make sure it runs that way. If it doesn't, you may get a more clear error.

Note that the error you're getting doesn't particularly look like it's coming from the `aws` command, of from the S3 service - which might talk about 'paths' or 'objects'. Rather, it's from the Python `subprocess` system & `Popen' call. I think those are via your call to`subprocess.call()`, but for some reason your line-of-code isn't shown. (How are you running the block of code with the`load_d2v()`?)

That suggests the file that's no found might be the `aws` command itself. Are you sure it's installed & runnable from the exact working-directory/environment that your Python is running in, and invoking via `subprocess.call()`?

(BTW, if my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61895560/130288) got you over your `sklearn.externals.joblib` problem, it'd be good for you to mark the answer as accepted, to save other potential answerers from thinking that's still an unsolved question that's blocking you.)

Answer (score 0):

try to add extension of your model file to your `fname` if you are confident the model file is there.
e.g. doc2vec_model.h3