# ImportError: cannot import name 'dump' from 'joblib' in Spyder

Tags: python, package, spyder, importerror

I am trying to run the following in Python using Spyder:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path = 'https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork-DA0101EN-SkillsNetwork/labs/Data%20files/automobileEDA.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path)
df.head()

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression #import linear_model from scikit-learn
lm=LinearRegression() #create a linear reg object using this cosntructor
```

But I get this Error message:

> from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression #import linear_model
> from scikit-learn lm=LinearRegression() #create a linear reg object
> using this cosntructor lm Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
> from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression #import linear_model from scikit-learn
>
> File
> "C:\Users\username.spyder-py3\site-packages\sklearn_*init*_.py",
> line 82, in 
> from .base import clone
>
> File "C:\Users\username.spyder-py3\site-packages\sklearn\base.py",
> line 17, in 
> from .utils import _IS_32BIT
>
> File
> "C:\Users\username.spyder-py3\site-packages\sklearn\utils_*init*_.py",
> line 24, in 
> from . import _joblib
>
> File
> "C:\Users\username.spyder-py3\site-packages\sklearn\utils_joblib.py",
> line 9, in 
> from joblib import dump, load
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'dump' from 'joblib'
> (C:\Users\username.spyder-py3\joblib_*init*_.py)

Comment: Please include full error traceback.

Comment: @DapperDuck just edited my question to include the traceback

Comment: Add this to your import statements: ```import joblib```. Not sure if it will work though.

Comment: Maybe this question can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61893719/importerror-cannot-import-name-joblib-from-sklearn-externals

Comment: Unfortunately with `import joblib` the error still remains

Comment: Did you try this:```import sklearn.external.joblib as extjoblib``` and ```import joblib```

Comment: Yes, same error :-/