# Data frames, importing csv files in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.externals import joblib
    
music_data = pd.read_csv('music.csv')
X = music_data.drop(columns=['genre'])
y = music_data['genre']
    
                     
model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X, y)
    
joblib.dump(model, 'music-recommender.joblib' )
```

This is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-28-802088a85507> in <module>
          1 import pandas as pd
          2 from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
    ----> 3 from sklearn.externals import joblib
          4 
          5 music_data = pd.read_csv('music.csv')

ImportError: cannot import name 'joblib' from 'sklearn.externals' (C:\Users\christian\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\__init__.py)*****
```

I would appreciate if someone could help out, is there another syntax that I should use to import `joblib` from sklearn?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name 'joblib' from 'sklearn.externals'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61893719/importerror-cannot-import-name-joblib-from-sklearn-externals)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I never knew that joblib was already install on my machine. just replace this line of code 
`from sklearn.externals import joblib` 
with
`import joblib`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here that you are trying to import `joblib` from scikit learn not reading csv file if you're wondering. Install [joblib](https://pypi.org/project/joblib/) using `pip install joblib` and import it like this

```py
import joblib
joblib.dump(model, 'music-recommender.joblib')
```

Remember to remove the import line from `sklearn.externals`. You can find more details here from the [official documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html) of `scikit-learn`.

Comment: thank you i installed the pip install joblib again in cmd and changed the syntax, so it works  now