# I am unable to run the app.py file for flask

Tags: python, flask

I am unable to run the app.py file for flask

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 256, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\admin\ML PYTHON\Fake_news_detection\App\app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sklearn.externals import joblib
ImportError: cannot import name 'joblib' from 'sklearn.externals' (c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\__init__.py)
```

Comment: looks like you are missing some library for sklearn

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name 'joblib' from 'sklearn.externals'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61893719/importerror-cannot-import-name-joblib-from-sklearn-externals)