# Error importing WatsonMachineLearningAPIClient (joblib error)

Tags: python, websphere, ibm-watson, joblib

I am trying to import *WatsonMachineLearningAPIClient*

```
from watson_machine_learning_client import WatsonMachineLearningAPIClient
```

But instead I'm getting the below error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'joblib' from 'sklearn.externals' (/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.8-CUDA/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/externals/__init__.py)
```

Please help!!

Comment: what's the relationship to websphere?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name 'joblib' from 'sklearn.externals'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61893719/importerror-cannot-import-name-joblib-from-sklearn-externals)