# I am having this issue in imports in Visual Studio and azure

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, scikit-learn, joblib

User program failed with ImportError: cannot import name '_joblib_parallel_args' from 'sklearn.utils.fixes' (/azureml-envs/azureml_39c082289e18c74c5b8523a75d2c0d1e/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py)

Anyone know why? Is there a workaround or a fix?

Answer (score 3):

Try

pip uninstall scikit-learn

pip install scikit-learn==1.0.2

Comment: That didn't work :/

Answer (score 1):

> The error shows that we are not able to import the '**_joblib_parallel_args**' from 'sklearn.utils.fixes'

**To fix this issue follow below ways:**

1. Uninstall and install the latest version of **scikit-learn**

```py
#uninstall sklearn
pip uninstall sklearn

#uninstall scikit-learn
pip uninstall scikit-learn

#install sklearn
pip install sklearn
```

2. Update **scikit-learn** into latest version

```py
# update the scikit-learn & sklearn
pip install --upgrade scikit-learn
```

3. You can directly import the **joblib** don't want to get from **'sklearn.utils.fixes**.

Instead of importing below format

```py
from sklearn.utils.fixes import joblib
```

You can use

```py
import joblib
```

#### Reference

- How to use joblib [Link 1](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) & [Link 2](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/model_persistence.html)
- [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61893719/importerror-cannot-import-name-joblib-from-sklearn-externals)

Comment: The first two approaches didn't really work. For the third one, joblib isn't really imported anywhere

For example it looks like this

File "/azureml-envs/azureml_5d64f04af177d0972b95fc1fe9e57c99/lib/python3.8/site-packages/imblearn/ensemble/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ._forest import BalancedRandomForestClassifier
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_5d64f04af177d0972b95fc1fe9e57c99/lib/python3.8/site-packages/imblearn/ensemble/_forest.py", line 28, in <module>
    from sklearn.utils.fixes import _joblib_parallel_args

Comment: can you share the code for line 8 which thrown the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
base ❯ pip install joblib
Requirement already satisfied: joblib in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.0.1)

base ❯ pip install --target=/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-package joblib
.......
Successfully installed joblib-1.1.0
```